# Reference raster data outside of GeoServer data directory

Tags: raster, geoserver

is there a possibility to point GeoServer to raster data stored neither in a database nor in the data directory of GeoServer?

My problem is that IT keeps me from direct access to the GeoServer machine and I only have access via a terminal machine. That keeps me from storing the data in the data directory.

Comment: yes - use the browse button to go to any directory that GeoServer can see.

Comment: hmm, Geoserver shows me only directories on the machine I cannot access. My data are on a different machine, dedicated to store geo-data.

Comment: Then no - the data has to be on a disk that geoserver can see

Comment: How do I define a directory well known to GeoServer?

Comment: Okay, found it here: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/data-dir-structure.html

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is YES, you can have data used by GeoServer that exists in a location other than the data_dir.  Also you should note that the data_dir itself doesn't have to be within the geoserver webapps folder.

For example (on a Windows server) to use a Raster Data Source (as part of a Add new Store operation) on your C: drive you could specify a Connection Parameter URL like:

```
file://C:\1Gdata\Emodnet\Aegean Sea - Levantine Sea [Multi Colour].tif
```

Comment: Note that the geoserver process user (whatever you are running it as, e.g. the tomcat user if that is how it is set up) needs permission to access that file.